# History Id received from pub/sub in gmail API after login and permissions to google account accepted

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I have the following express app, that is hit by a login endpoint after it successfully gets a google code from user authentication.

I get a successful historyId back after verifying the code and submitting to the gmail api a watch function, but I have no idea what to do with it at this point.

Am I getting close to the point where my server will see notifications when I send a email from the authenticated gmail account?

What are my next steps, I don't follow the Google documentation at this point.

I basically want to see data come in when a user sends an email, and I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { PORT } = process.env;
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const { OAuth2Client } = require("google-auth-library");

const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
  process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT
);

const gmail = google.gmail({
  version: "v1",
  auth: oAuth2Client,
});

app.post(URL, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.code);

  // Now that we have the code, use that to acquire tokens.
  const r = await oAuth2Client.getToken(req.body.code);

  oAuth2Client.setCredentials(r.tokens);

  //   const response = oauth2Client.getToken(req.body.code);
  console.log("r", await r);

  const reser = await gmail.users.watch({
    userId: "me",
    requestBody: {
      topicName: `projects/express-server-connection/topics/MyTopic`,
      labelIds: ["INBOX"],
    },
  });
  console.log(reser.data);

  res.send(r);
});

app.listen(PORT, async () => {
  // setting up our webhook url on server spinup
  try {
    console.log(`Server is up and Running at PORT : ${PORT}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: labelIds: ["SENT"], <-- maybe?

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. Even when I go into google cloud and look at the pub sub no message shows up there. I am really confused at this point. But I do get a historyId and expiration object.

Comment: Ok It started working, because I was sending the email to myself to test and it didn't pick that up so I sent to another account of mine it works. You can, make that the answer if you like.

Comment: Hi @AndersKitson, Did the above suggestion help?

Comment: Yes it did, I got the pulling information. I still have to run users.history.list with the historyId and then users.message.get with the message id to get the actual email. But yes it did help.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the comments,  the issue was resolved by changing the labelID from  `Inbox` to `Sent` as mentioned by @DalmTo.